# Formatting the first row of data and stop when the data ends

Tags: excel, vba

So I am trying to write this simple VBA code to take the first row of data (which will be bunch of field heads, amount will vary depending on data sheet I am working with) and format it applying a filter and header style.

My goal is to make it stop applying the header when the data ends (it could end at column H or AZ just depends on the sheet I'm working with). The filter seems to be working just fine, but the header likes to keep applying to the entire row.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `cells(1,myCol).select` after `Selection.AutoFilter` and before `Selection.Style = "Heading 2"`

Comment: Excellent, this worked! but my filters are not applying now so I need to figure that out now. Thank you though!

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refer to a single cell instead of a row, you need to specify a column number as well.

Try something like:

```
    Dim myCol As Long
    myCol = 1
    While Cells(1, myCol).Value <> ""
        ActiveSheet.Cells(1, myCol).Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Selection.Style = "Heading 2"
        myCol = myCol + 1
    Wend
```

---

### More Info

- [Referring to Ranges in Excel VBA](http://excelmatters.com/referring-to-ranges-in-vba/)